# Cuando paso el cursor por al lado se activa el menu, ¿cómo soluciono este error?

Tags: html, css, menu

Cuando paso el cursor por *al lado se activa el menú*, ¿cómo soluciono este error?

¿Cómo hago para que se active solamente cuando el cursor esté encima de `Categorías`?

Les paso mi código https://codepen.io/Mazzion123/pen/ExNrwBY

Intenté varias formas con `width` y otras más, pero no pude solucionarlo.

```css
#menu {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  top: 0vw;
}

body {
  background: #000;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#menu li {
  position: relative;
  left: -30px;
}

#menu ul {
  list-style: none;
}

#menu li>a {
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  min-width: 100px;
  font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  position: auto;
  left: 92px;
}

#menu li>a:hover {
  color: #FF0000;
  transition: all .4s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
}

#menu>li {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

#menu>li>ul {
  display: none;
}

#menu>li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -90px;
  top: 36px;
}

#menu>li:hover>ul+#menu2 {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 36px;
}
```

```html
<!---MENU--->
<nav>
  <ul id="menu">
    <li><i class="fas fa-home home"></i><a href="">Inicio</a></li>
    <li><i class="far fa-star star"></i>
      <a id="categoria">Categorias</a>
      <ul>
        <li> <a href="#">Accion</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#">Terror</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#">Suspenso</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#">Musicales</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#">Aventura</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#">Comedia</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#">Crimen</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#">Ciencia Ficcion</a></li>


      </ul>

      <ul id="menu2">
        <ul>
          <li> <a href="#">Accion1</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#">Terror1</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#">Suspenso1</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#">Musicales1</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#">Aventura1</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#">Comedia1</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#">Crimen1</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#">Ciencia Ficcion1</a></li>

        </ul>
      </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Aquí tienes una respuesta basada solo en HTML y CSS, el único problema es que no se de dónde viene el punto en la esquina superior derecha de Inicio, ya que probé a quitarle el , pero no dio resultado.

El problema era que los

Inicio y Categorías estaban solapados el uno con el otro, por eso, al pasar por encima del punto, se te abrían las categorías, añadiendo o bien un float a todos, un margin a ambos lados del punto y demás, consigues el resultado que quieres.

También estaban mal cerrados los

y los , lo que puede que hiciera peor el solapamiento. Igualmente, revisa que todo esté en orden tal y como tu lo quieres.

(Mi consejo de todo lo que llevo andado con html y css hasta ahora, para probar los límites de los div, ul, li etc, ponlos un background de distintos colores, o un hover con el background, así sabes dónde empieza y termina cada uno, y nunca se te solaparán)

```css
#menu {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  top: 0vw;
}

body {
  background: #000;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li i.fa-star{
  margin: 0 15px;
  float: left;
}

#menu li {
  position: relative;
  left: -30px;
}

#menu ul {
  list-style: none;
}

#menu li>a {
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  min-width: 100px;
  font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  position: auto;
  left: 92px;
}
#menu li>a:hover {
  color: #FF0000;
  transition: all .4s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
}

#menu>li {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

#menu>li>ul {
  display: none;
}

#menu>li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -90px;
  top: 36px;
}

#menu>li:hover>ul+#menu2 {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 36px;
}

#inicio{
  float: left;;
}
#categoria{
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>NAV</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<!---MENU--->
<nav>
  <ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="inicio">Inicio</a></li>
    <li><i class="far fa-star star"></i></li>
    <li><a id="categoria">Categorias</a>
      <ul>
        <li> <a href="#">Accion</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#">Terror</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#">Suspenso</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#">Musicales</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#">Aventura</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#">Comedia</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#">Crimen</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#">Ciencia Ficcion</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul id="menu2">
        <ul>
          <li> <a href="#">Accion1</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#">Terror1</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#">Suspenso1</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#">Musicales1</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#">Aventura1</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#">Comedia1</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#">Crimen1</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#">Ciencia Ficcion1</a></li>
        </ul>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Si tienes razon con lo que has dicho, pero el codigo que me pasaste no me funciono sigue con el mismo problema, esos punto solo debes eliminar <li><i class="far fa-star star"></i>, le puse un icono de estrellas de ahi viene

Comment: Entonces, quieres que solamente se despliegue el ul cuando esté encima del texto "categorias", no encima de su contenedor?

Comment: si eso quiero, Exacto!!

Answer (score 0):

Creo que programando un evento `click` con JavaScript.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.parent').click(function() {
    $('.sub-nav').toggleClass('visible');
  });
});
```

```css
#nav ul.sub-nav {
  display: none;
}

#nav ul.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="nav">
  <li>Inicio</li>
  <li class="parent">Categorias
    <ul class="sub-nav">
      <li>Accion1</li>
      <li>Terror1</li>
      <li>Suspenso</li>
      <li>Musicals</li>
      <li>Aventuras</li>
      <li>Comedia</li>
      <li>Crimen1</li>
      <li>Ciencia Ficcion</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Otro Menu</li>
</ul>
```

Solo se activaría el menu cuando le des click en la etiqueta que necesites
Fuente [SO Ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18787019/4668184)

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero yo no quiero darle click en la etiqueta, quiero solo pasar el maus y que se abra el menu. el problema es que yo no estoy pasando el cursor por "Categorias" y se activa igual

Answer (score 0):

Prueba agregando esta regla css:

```
    a#categoria {
       /* border: 1px solid; */
       padding-right: 0!important;
       padding-left: 0!important;
       min-width: 0!important;
       width: fit-content;
    }
```

puedes descomentar la propiedad border para que veas el area que ocupa el elemento, si pasas el cursor por esa area se activara segun tu codigo.